# How to fetch attribute in JSON object/array

Tags: php, json

I am currently using Amazon AWS SNS to send SMS to customers.

SMS works fine however I would like to simply display a success or error message when the form has been submitted depending on the outcome.

result after form submit on successful message below. I can see that statusCode with int(200) means that it was sent successfully. How can I fetch this and use it to display success or error message?

```
object(Aws\Result)#117(2){
  [
    "data": "Aws\Result": private
  ]=>array(2){
    [
      "MessageId"
    ]=>string(36)"f12f2261-5e13-54e8-b72e-37s26fd3c348"[
      "@metadata"
    ]=>array(4){
      [
        "statusCode"
      ]=>int(200)[
        "effectiveUri"
      ]=>string(35)"https://sns.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"[
        "headers"
      ]=>array(4){
        [
          "x-amzn-requestid"
        ]=>string(36)"716dase5-f048-5d35-8af0-sf36ce583d95"[
          "content-type"
        ]=>string(8)"text/xml"[
          "content-length"
        ]=>string(3)"294"[
          "date"
        ]=>string(29)"Tue, 18 Jun 2019 19:31:28 GMT"
      }[
        "transferStats"
      ]=>array(1){
        [
          "http"
        ]=>array(1){
          [
            0
          ]=>array(0){

          }
        }
      }
    }
  }[
    "monitoringEvents": "Aws\Result": private
  ]=>array(0){

  }
}
```

php code:

```
if(isset($_POST['gateeway'])){

    $sender_id = $_POST['sender_id'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $topic = 'arn:aws:sns:eu-west-1:52732446504:Testing';

    try {
        $result = $sns->publish([
            'TargetArn' => $topic,
            'Message' => $message,
            'MessageAttributes' => [
                'AWS.SNS.SMS.SenderID' => [
                    'DataType' => 'String', 
                    'StringValue' => $sender_id,
                ],
                'AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType' => [
                    'DataType' => 'String',
                    'StringValue' => 'Promotional',
                ]
            ]
        ]);
        var_dump($result);
    } catch (AwsException $e) {
        // output error message if fails
        error_log($e->getMessage());
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the status code like this

```
$metaInfo = $result->get('@metadata');
if($metaInfo ['statusCode'] === 200){
  echo "Message Sent";
}
```